# Warning when I want to delete a record in a datatable

Tags: jquery, vue.js, datatable

I am working with Laravel 5.6 and Vue. I implemented Datatables and all functions are working correctly. However when I want to delete a record I get a warning:

> DataTables warning: table id=myTable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

This warning only appears when I want to delete a record, not when I create one or modify one. The code of my datatable is the following

```js
mytable() {
  jQuery.noConflict();
  $(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable(({
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
        'copyHtml5',
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5',
        'pdfHtml5'
      ]
    }));
  });
},
```

**my code to delete in laravel is**

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        if (!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');
        $categoria=Categoria::destroy($request->id);
        return $categoria;
        //
       
    }
```

**the code in js using axios**

```
axios.delete('/categoria/eliminar',{
                        'id':id
                    }).then(function(response){
                        me.listarCategoria();
                       console.log(response);
                        swal(
                        'Eliminado!',
                        'El registro ha sido eliminado con éxito.',
                        'success'
                        )
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
```

Comment: What does the link say that is mentioned in the error message?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show us how you are deleting a record? How do we recreate your error? ([mre])

Comment: modify the question showing the code to remove